# Rename file name in the loop

Tags: files, rename

I have a loop and I want to select some columns with awk and do sort, and then rename my output file with a new name. My awk and sort are working well, but I want to get a file name with a different name of my input file and I was not able to do it. 
I have different directories to run this loop: a, b and c.
The command is:

```
for i in a b c 
do
    (cd $i/; for i in *_test2.txt; do awk '{print $2"_"$1}' $i | sort -V > ${i%.txt}3.txt; done)
done
```

I would like to change the name of the file to `*_test3.txt`, but in my loop I will have the output as `*_test23.txt`
How can I do that?

Comment: You're doing something else than renaming files there. What's with the `awk` and `sort`?

Comment: Yes, I am using awk to get some specific columns and sort the lines and then generate the new file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${i%.txt}` will just remove the `.txt` extension from the filename `$i`.  To pick off one extra character, use `${i%?.txt}`:

```
for i in {a,b,c}/*_test2.txt; do
  awk '{ print $2 "_" $1 }' "$i" | sort -V -o "${i%?.txt}3.txt"
done
```